# Step-by-step checklist for iOS

Tags: ios, ipad, applications, productivity

I am looking for an app that works on the Mac as well as on the iPad.

At work we have daily tasks that do not occur on a set schedule (aka they are on an as needed basis).

This app would allow us to create checklists for these tasks (think pre-flight checklist for airline pilots) that would be "resettable" and reusable.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There's quite a few cross-plattform Todo apps. OmniFocus seems to be the most feature-rich currently (this might be subjective)

Answer (score 1):

There's a ton of different ToDo list apps out there. Personally I have used [OmniFocus](https://www.omnigroup.com/omnifocus/) and [ToDoIst](https://todoist.com/).

**OmniFocus**

- (subjectively) the nicest interface
- sync between platforms with the free OmniSync Service
- "Apple" (iOS and OSX) only; not on Windows or Linux; no web interface
- not cheap

  **ToDoIst**:
- available for all kinds of platforms, including a web interface
- free version to get started; premium version with add. features
- "template" feature might help you implement and re-use your checklists
- tasks can be shared between / assigned to ToDoIst users